# py2app/Tkinter application error: "classic environment is no longer supported"

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, py2app

So, I created a simple GUI app using Tkinter, py2app, and numpy. When I run it on my computer it works fine. However, I tested it on a few other computers and kept getting the error:
"You can't open the application because the classic environment is no longer supported."
I'm not sure I understand the error. The other computers had the same python versions and OS versions as I do? Is there something additional I need to do to make my app work on other machines?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Mac world `classic environment` is a software abstraction layer that allowed old Mac apps (e.g G5 hardware architecture) to be executed on new Mac architecture (Intel hardware architecture). Classic environment was supported on `pre-10.5` versions of Mac OS X and then dropped in newer versions.

py2app supports command-line arguments for building executables to support different architectures, look closer at `--arch` parameter of py2app.

Comment: I see, thanks. What is it about py2app apps that require classic environment to run? And will the --arch be part of the setup.py file?

Answer (score 1):

To pull this back from the void.

I was having a similar issue. The MAC I was developing on was running 10.8.Something. The target machine was running 10.6+ and I was getting `classic environment is no longer supported` errors. I looked into architecture flags to no avail. I did find my issues. When emailing the .app (drag and drop into gmail in chrome) to the client the filesize was only 1kb. On the development machine the filesize showed 25Mb+. Pulling this 1kb file from the emails and launching it on the development machine I also got the same error. Turns out drag and drop is not sufficient. I successfully zipped the .app and was able to eliminate this error.

Comment: Had this same problem just copying across a network. So thanks for posting this.